# Counting unique IP addresses with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count the total number of unique IP addresses using MySQL, this is what I have for my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count` FROM `pageviews` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '1299675600' AND '1299762000' GROUP BY `client_ip`
```

The only problem I have, is it is counting the results made by that IP address, is there a way in MySQL to only count each lot of IP addresses, counting them uniquely, rather than grouping them and then counting them.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried with `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to count the number of unique ip addresses. I'm not entirely sure what your question is but you could try this, or adapt it to suit your needs:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_ip) as `count`
FROM `pageviews`
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '1299675600' AND '1299762000'
```

Comment: First comment, best answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
select count(distinct client_ip) as total_num
from pageviews
where `timestamp` BETWEEN '1299675600' AND '1299762000'
```

There, you'll count the number of `distinct` ip addresses -- which should be what you want ; and no need for the `group by` clause anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `client_ip`) as `count` FROM `pageviews` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '1299675600' AND '1299762000'
```

There's no need to group by client_ip since you can already query the distinct values using the DISTINCT keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT in the COUNT():

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_ip) as `count` 
FROM `pageviews` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '1299675600' AND '1299762000'
```